# jboss downloaded but where could I start to make work

Tags: java, jboss

well I studied java language and I'm pretty sure I'm at a good point and I would move up to the next level beginning to build a web app. So I downloaded and installed jboss but I think although is a complete framework it's very complicated.so I ask you where couid I start?which could the beginning point to understand something and move on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss is only one of several web application containers available in the Java ecosystem. If I were you I'd start by looking at how to develop web components using servlets and jsp. Basically the things included in the Oracle Web Component Developer Certification. While it's certainly not necessary to get a certification it is good to have a grasp of the material covered. There are plenty of books and online resources that cover these topics.